# Fluctuating values in Newton Raphson

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I'm trying to find N root using Newton Raphson method. Here is my implementation for the same...

```
double derive(int guess, int m, int n) {
  return guess - (pow(guess, n)-m)/(n*pow(guess, n-1));
}

double getNRoot(int m, int n) {
  double guess = 1;
  double nextGuess = derive(guess, m, n);
  while (fabs(guess-nextGuess) >= 0.0001) {
    guess = nextGuess;
    nextGuess = derive(guess, m, n);
    printf ("%f %f\n", guess, nextGuess);
  }
  return nextGuess;
}
```

It works for many values, but for `m=8` and `n=4`. The `guess` and `nextGuess` fluctuates between two values when `m=8` and `n=4`.

```
2.750000 1.750000
1.750000 2.750000
2.750000 1.750000
...
```

So what is wrong here?

Comment: Why pow(guess, n) - m ?  Get rid of that -m ... needs to be xn - f(xn)/f'(xn)

Comment: @GuySirton- I'm following [the article at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method#Examples), it says otherwise.

Comment: OK.  My mistake, your f(x) is indeed (y^n-m)...

Comment: OK. as answered below if you make guess a double in the function prototype everything should work...  Your guess passed as an int rounds it down to an integer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derive function returns a double but manipulate int variables. Even if on function call you supply int, you can put doubles in the function prototype to have the proper precision:

```
 double derive(double guess, double m, double n) {
   return guess - (pow(guess, n)-m)/(n*pow(guess, n-1));
 }
```

Or at least declare local double variables for the non-pow uses:

```
 double derive(int guess, int m, int n) {
   double d_guess = guess;
   double d_n = n;
   double d_m = m
   return d_guess - (pow(d_guess, n)-d_m)/(d_n*pow(d_guess, n-1));
 }
```

You should probably review you whole implementation considering that. That is, use doubles when "real" numbers are needed and "int" where "integer" numbers are used.

Comment: Yeah.  It's really the guess that matters assuming he doesn't care that m and n can only be ints.  Also no need for the d_guess if you're passing a double already.

Comment: I agree. Copy paste mistake. Fixed now ;)

Comment: Your edit is still wrong.  This won't work because guess is an int so we'll never converge...  Remember that ints will get promoted to doubles anyways.